# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES on a debug build when using 'Run' button

Tags: android, android-studio

So I was just making a toy app to test capturing photos and video for an app at work. I set up everything in a standard fashion, make a small activity and when I try to use the 'Run' command in android studio to install on my device, I get the following error:

```
11/28 11:14:32: Launching 'app' on Unknown Device.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
APK signature verification failed.
Retry
```

I tried searching google as to why this might happen, but I only found things concerning the generation of a signed apk and usually in a release build. I have done no signing configs on this project. It's basically a standard Android Studio generated project. Here's a screenshot of my gradle file:

[module-gradle-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlOlB.png)

Has anyone encountered this problem? I'm using Android Studio 3.5, gradle 5.4.1 and gradle plugin 3.5.0

**UPDATE**

So, I decided to just restart the adb server and it worked. The question of why this happened, though, remains